# Autoloading local composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

Ive read several questions on this topic, but I still cant figure it out. 
I have a library that I want to put in the ~/vendor folder and use the built in composer autoloader.
My package is called "beep". The directory structure is

```
vendor/beep
vendor/beep/beep
vendor/beep/beep/src
vendor/beep/beep/src/Beep
vendor/beep/beep/src/Beep/Request.php
```

Request.php starts with:

```
namespace Beep;
class Request { ....
```

composer.json ends with

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-0": {"Beep\\": "src/Beep"}
}
```

and still when I try to do:

```
$r = new Beep\Request();
```

I get :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Beep\Request' not found in ....
```

The autoloading for all other packages is working. 
I am doing composer update and it claims its generating autoload files.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: where is your `composer.json` file located

Comment: Did you do a `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: composer.json is located in vendor/beep/beep/composer.json on the same level as "src" folder.

Yes, I tried composer dump-autoload and its says its generating autoload files without any error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you define PSR-0 autoloading, the name of the class will be entirely converted to the path and file name and then appended to the path you say contains the prefix.

In contrast, if you define PSR-4 autoloading, the prefix mentioned gets stripped from the class name, and the remaining parts get converted to a path and file name and then appended to the path.

```
"psr-0": {"Beep\\": "src/Beep"}
```

If you autoload a class `\Beep\Request`, it will be searched at `src/Beep/Beep/Request.php`.

```
"psr-4": {"Beep\\": "src/Beep"}
```

Nearly the same here, but because "Beep" gets stripped of the classname first, the remaining classname is `Request`, and the search path then is `src/Beep/Request.php`.

It is however recommended to keep the path length to a minimum, so I would recommend this:

```
"psr-4": {"Beep\\": "src"}
```

And then remove the probably empty "Beep" directory (you cannot have a `Beep.php` file at this level because it cannot contain a valid namespaced class, and any other prefix wouldn't match). Your `Beep\Request` class would then be located at `src/Request.php`.

Comment: After several attempts I just changed
"psr-0": {"Beep\\": "src/Beep"} to "psr-4": {"Beep\\": "src/Beep"},
executed composer dump-autoload and it seems to be working. 
Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention that in bootstrap I added: 
$loader = require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('Beep', __DIR__.'/vendor/beep/beep/src/');

Comment: That adding is wrong. Composer takes care of everything, provided you are doing it right...